# Import data from Teradata using logstash jdbc plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

Could some body please tell me how to use log stash JDBC plugin for Teradata?

The problem with Teradata is it requires two java_driver_files (tdgssconfig.jar and terajdbc4.jar) to be listed. How to specify two files terajdbc4.jar and tdgssconfig.jar

I have tried many ways like:

```
input {
    JDBC {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:teradata://localhost/MYDB"

        jdbc_user => "dbc"

        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/TeraJDBC/terajdbc4.jar;/home/TeraJDBC/tdgssconfig.jar"

        jdbc_driver_class => "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"

        statement => "SELECT * from MYDB.Acct"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

This is not recognizing the class path of driver library, how do I specify two jar files in the driver library?

Answer (score 1):

With logstash 2.3.1, we're separating the jars with a comma...

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/jars/terajdbc4.jar,/usr/jars/tdgssconfig.jar"
...
```

Good luck!

Guy

Answer (score 0):

This is working for ver: 6.4.3

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "terajdbc4.jar,tdgssconfig.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:teradata://server.com/database=DB_name"
jdbc_user => "user"
jdbc_password => "password"
statement => "SELECT Column FROM Table"
 }
}

output {
stdout {
codec => json_lines}
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
index => "index_name"
user => "user"
password => "password"
 }
}
```